# Get list of default GCC warnings

Tags: gcc, warnings

I'd like to know if it's possible to get a list of warnings that are enabled in GCC when no -Wx or -W-no-x flags are specified? I need this because I've got 2 different GCC versions (namely 3.3 and 4.3) which react differently on the same code with the same compilation flags.

For example, 4.3 with no additional warning options throws a warning when signed-to-unsigned comparison occurs while 3.3 does only if -Wsign-compare flag. So, I'd like to figure out, which flags should I add to gcc-3.3 to force it to detect the same warnings 4.3 does by default.

For 4.3 I'd managed to get such list of warnings using `gcc -Q --help=warnings | grep enabled`, but 3.3 doesn't seems to provide such function. Does anybody know, how it can be done in any other way? Maybe the source file that defines warning states?

Regards,
Marvin

Comment: Check the manuals for both versions? They should contain the complete detail.

Comment: Check the NEWS file in the source distribution.

Answer (score 1):

GCC command line options are usually defined in gcc/common.opt file.
Try searching for `Warning' keyword in this file.